# QTabWidget setCurrentIndex not working as expected

Tags: c++, qt5

I am trying to change the view to the main tab when a user clicks on the second tab of `QTabWidget` if a certain condition is met, but when I call `setCurrentIndex()` inside of `on_tabWidget_tabBarClicked()`, the view stays on the current tab. Please see the code below.

If I call `setCurrentIndex()` outside of `on_tabWidget_tabBarClicked()`, then it works.

```
void MainWindow::on_tabWidget_tabBarClicked(int index)
{
    if (index == 1)
    {
        Error("Empty, back to main");
        ui->tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try changing `ui->tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(0);` to `QTimer::singleShot(100, [this](){ui->tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(0)});`

Comment: Thanks it works! Could you please explain why it works? Is the tab still loading after calling setCurrentIndex(0) so a delay is required? BTW, you missed out a semicolon after setCurrentIndex(0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your case is that when the signal is triggered even your mouse is on the QTabWidget so even if you change the tab with setCurrentIndex(0) then the mouse event will change it back to 1. In this case the logic is change it a moment later and for this a QTimer is used:

```cpp
void MainWindow::on_tabWidget_tabBarClicked(int index)
{
   if(index==1)
   {
       Error("Empty, back to main");
       QTimer::singleShot(100, [this](){ ui->tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(0); });
   }
}
```

Comment: timeout `0` is probably enough (and actually safer, as 100ms is quite a long time and might introduce strange behaviours, once user interface gets complicated).

Answer (score 1):

Using the slot on_tabWidget_currentChanged instead of tabBarClicked would also work correctly since this is called once the tab change is complete. That would avoid the need to call the asynchronous QTimer.

```
void MainWindow::on_tabWidget_currentChanged(int index)
{
    if (index == 1)
    {
        Error("Empty, back to main");
        ui->tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(0);
    }
}
```